# Don't insert formular data double after refresh

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I build a small php framework by my one and i looking for the most common way to insert formular data to mysql.. currently i use the normal "insert" query.. but I have the problem that after a page refresh the data stored twice in the database.

The most documents I read said, to implement a redirect function after sending the formular. I this the most common way?

I'm not looking for a easy solution but for only that I can use for every formular I will use in the future. but keep in mind all formular store to a different database.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What I think you are asking is what to do after a query has been run. You will need to reload the page so that query does not run again if the page is refreshed. Thats why you are getting ,ultiple lines in your database.
 Something like this

```
$redirect_page= "index.php";//plus any URL segments index.php/news/articles/item/123
header(sprintf("Location: %s", $redirect_page));
```

Good luck

Keith

Comment: i currently do that.. but i think it's not the best way? if you have 10 different formular.. you always put this line code after the formular? i hope it would exist some solution like to create a class.. but i don't find anything to make this step more automatically.. but otherwise.. thanks for your comment.. current i use strtok to cut the url after ? and store the url before ? in my varibale. that i redirect to